# failed to copy of a series of file using the for loop, cannot find the problem

Tags: bash

I was trying to copy some files with numbering with `for i in {};do cp ***;done`, but I have encountered an error.

```
$ for i in {0..2};do cp ./CTCC_noSDS_0$i_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs 3_dataset_pool/;done

cp: cannot stat ‘./CTCC_noSDS_0.bwt2pairs.validPairs’: No such file or directory

cp: cannot stat ‘./CTCC_noSDS_0.bwt2pairs.validPairs’: No such file or directory

cp: cannot stat ‘./CTCC_noSDS_0.bwt2pairs.validPairs’: No such file or directory
```

The file name look like below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jiangxu lc_lc 456M Nov 12 20:22 CTCC_noSDS_00_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs

-rw-r--r-- 1 jiangxu lc_lc 466M Nov 12 20:23 CTCC_noSDS_01_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs

-rw-r--r-- 1 jiangxu lc_lc 473M Nov 12 20:23 CTCC_noSDS_02_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
```

I can cp the file one by one manually but can not use the for loop. It seems that the system just ignored the `$i` for no reason, So, could anyone tell me what is the problem with the command?

Comment: you show both `for I in {}` and `for i in {0..2}` . In any case try refrencing as `${i}`. And please use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to achieve correct formatting for `code/data/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: Please try to surround `i` with curly braces as `${i}` in your command, otherwise it is interpreted as a part of a variable name `i_hg19` which is undefined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The shell did not ignore the variable. You are misusing variable expansion. Valid characters for variable names include underscores (one of which you have next to `$i`). So, what the shell is actually seeing is a variable called `i__hg19`, which is undefined. Thus, the filename is unexistent.

The solution is to wrap `$i` between curly braces like this:

```
cp ./CTCC_noSDS_0${i}_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
```

Comment: This doesn't work for files with numbers greater than 9.

Comment: No, because you will have a `0` prior to the index in the case where the index is greater than 9.

Comment: For example, if he had the file: `CTCC_noSDS_22_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs` . Your code will look for `CTCC_noSDS_022_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs` instead.

Comment: Of course, he would need to modify the template. This is a case-specific solution. But I think that's very obvious for the average man.

Comment: Cool, just making sure it is obvious.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. The double digit issue can be solved using for i in {00..**}, ** represent any number greater than 00.

Answer (score 0):

## Using a similar method to the OP

You can do something like this (call this script `b.bash`):

```
#!/bin/bash
DST_DIR=./mydir/
SRC_DIR=./

for i in {1..5}; do
    echo "[*] Trying to find files with number $i"
    if [ "$i" -lt 10 ]; then
        potential_file="$SRC_DIR/CTCC_noSDS_0${i}_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs"
    else
        potential_file="$SRC_DIR/CTCC_noSDS_${i}_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs"
    fi

    if [ -f "$potential_file" ]; then
        echo "[!] Moving $potential_file"
        cp "$potential_file" "$DST_DIR"
    fi
done
```

Let us say we have the following in the current directory:

```
$ ls -1
b.bash
CTCC_noSDS_00_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
CTCC_noSDS_01_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
CTCC_noSDS_02_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
CTCC_noSDS_12_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
mydir
```

And let us say we want to copy these files to `mydir`. If we run the above script, we see this output:

```
$ ./b.bash
[*] Trying to find files with number 1
[!] Moving .//CTCC_noSDS_01_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
[*] Trying to find files with number 2
[!] Moving .//CTCC_noSDS_02_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
[*] Trying to find files with number 3
[*] Trying to find files with number 4
[*] Trying to find files with number 5
```

Then looking in `mydir` we see the files:

```
$ ls -1 mydir/
CTCC_noSDS_01_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
CTCC_noSDS_02_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs
```

- Note that the above for loop only goes to `5`. You can modify that as
  you see fit.
- Note the if statement in the for loop and what it is
  for.

## Using find : )

You can instead use the `find` command like so:

```
find . -type f -iname 'CTCC_noSDS_*_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs' -exec bash -c 'cp {} mydir/' \;
```

Here is a safer/stricter `find` command using regex:

```
find . -regextype sed -regex ".*CTCC_noSDS_[0-9]\+_hg19.bwt2pairs.validPairs" -exec bash -c 'cp {} ./mydir/' \;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it later.:)